# Evaluate page & store in variable?

Tags: php, variables, evaluate

I want to grab a php file, evaluate any php, then store the contents in a variable.

We'll call this.. **page.php**

```
<?php
$content = "Hello World.";
?>

<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $content ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $content ?>
</body>
</html
```

And I want to put that into a variable by calling a function from another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) before including the file, and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) after.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can evaluate any string as a PHP code with function eval;
http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php